# Change Datetime by joda does not work- no error message and Time remains unchanged

Tags: android, android-jodatime

I want to change datetime in my android app using joda Datetime using my below code.
steps:

1. get current date of system
2. set system hours
3. get current date and check the result.

There was no error pop-up while running this app.
But the time was not change.

Is there anything that im missing?
Do I need to get more permission in Manifest.xml?

Note that the app will be run on a rooted emulator.

My file as below:

MainActivity.java;

```
private void settime1(){

        List<String> text = new ArrayList<>();
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,now.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    text.add("Now: " + now);
    text.add("Now + 12 hours: " + now.plusHours(12));
    Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, currentTime.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.us_bbteam">
```

buid.gradle

```
dependencies {
    api 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10.9:no-tzdb'

    implementation "androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:1.0'
    implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.10.9.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess. Calculating the time 12 hours form now in Joda-Time foes not change the system clock of your phone.

Comment: Thanks for your link.  Actually the link about changing time using "su date" cmd.  I have tried to follow the cmd but my app just crash immediately after executing cmd. Note that i have grant superuser access to the app.

Comment: The `java.util` Date-Time API is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html). Also, read this notice at the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/): *Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.* I highly recommend you use [the solution given by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69140048/10819573).

Comment: Did you see "It's possible and has been done. You need `android.permission.SET_TIME`. Afterward use the `AlarmManager` via `Context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)` and its method `setTime()`."?

Answer (score 1):

### java.time.Clock

Consider using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. java.time also offers a `Clock` that you can configure to give you a different time from the real current time.

```
    Clock offsetClock
            = Clock.offset(Clock.systemDefaultZone(), Duration.ofHours(12));
    
    ZonedDateTime offsetNow = ZonedDateTime.now(offsetClock);
    System.out.println(offsetNow);
```

When I ran this just now — 6:38 AM in my time zone — I got:

> 2021-09-11T18:38:00.356242+02:00[Europe/Copenhagen]

If you need an old-fashioned `Date` object for an API that you cannot afford to upgrade to java.time just now, draw an `Instant` from the clock and convert:

```
    Date offsetOldfashionedDate = Date.from(Instant.now(offsetClock));
    System.out.println(offsetOldfashionedDate);
```

> Sat Sep 11 18:38:00 CEST 2021

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: thanks alot for your advice in detail.
I have tried to use Clock.systemdefaultZone(), but my app was just stop working immediately( app crash). Im not sure how to solve this

Comment: Sorry to read. I am wondering whether it could be a limitation in desugaring if you’re using that, I am far from sure though, it’s just a thought. I have tested my code on desktop Java only. I am no Android developer myself and have not had an opportunity to test on Android.